# nHibernate generate Guid for Id but property as string

Tags: c#, nhibernate, activerecord, asp.net-identity, castle-activerecord

I am trying to make an nHibernate entity that implements `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser` but I want to use Guids for the `Id` key property.  I am building this in a Castle ActiveRecord environment.

I'm writing a property in my `User` class per the interface like so:

```
public class User : IUser
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is populate the `Id` column with a generated Guid in the database, but populate the `Id` property in the entity with a Guid string.

I thought I'd be good with overriding `NHibernate.Id.TableGenerator` like so:

```
public class GuidStringGenerator : TableGenerator
{
    public override object Generate(ISessionImplementor session, object obj)
    {
        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

... but now I think won't actually accomplish what I want; it seems this would make a string value in the database instead of a Guid.

Any wisdom on how this would be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Jeremy Holovacs,

you could implement the Id-Property of IUser explicit.

```
public class User : IUser
{
  public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
  string IUser.Id{get{return this.Id.ToString();}}
  public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Greetings
Juy Juka

Comment: Hmm.  I've never done that before.  I will try it out.